# Получить из строки все числа

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

у меня есть строка

```
case 14400: $m = 4636; $b = 0; break;
```

как вытащить оттуда число 4636 и 0?? (По отдельности, в разные переменные)

Comment: Для любителей извращенного программирования :)  
Извлекаем регулярным выражением сразу в переменные с теми же именами:  

    $s="case 14400: \$taksovat_money = 4636; \$taksovat_baks = 20; break;";
    $re="/\\\$([a-z0-9_]+)\\s*=\\s*(\\d+);/ie";
    preg_replace($re, "\$\\1=\\2;", $s);
    echo $taksovat_money."\n".$taksovat_baks;
Результат:  

    4636
    20
http://ideone.com/vdFp8f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "case 14400: \$taksovat_money = 4636; \$taksovat_baks = 0; break;";
preg_match_all('#= ([0-9]*);#Usi', $string, $return);
var_dump($return);
```

ПС. Учи регулярные выражения, очень нужная вещь в программировании.

Comment: никак не могу х норм понять ((( сможешь мне объяснить текущее выражение?

Comment: Скобки означают какую область сохранить в элемент массива. Ищем общее у числа 4636 и 0. Они обы стоят после "= " и после них стоит ";". В скобках у нас находится само число. Перед ним мы пишем должно стоять "= ", после ";". Я не педагог. Объяснять не умею, всё то что я знаю по регулярным выражениям, тем более в такой простой ситуации, считаю очевидным. Лучше просто почитайте статьи.

Comment: Ну и чего? Вам это ни о чём не говорит? Если нет - то до регулярных выражений вам ещё учится и учится. Вы даже массивы не знаете... Вы получили массив, искомые числа находятся в $return[1]

Answer (score -1):

```
[0-9]+[0-9]+
```