# Подскажите шаблон регулярного выражения для вычленения числа из строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пример строки: от 5 276 руб.

Нужно шаблон для `preg_replace`, для числа 5276.

Так же прошу учитывать что помимо самой строки может быть различный html код

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/204954/183314

Comment: "Так же прошу учитывать что помимо самой строки может быть различный html код" - это все равно ничего не объясняет. Встречаться другие подобные конструкции там могут, например, еще одно число, обрамленное словами "от" и "руб"? Тегом каким-то может все это обрамлено будет, который уникальный в этой строке? У вас там раньше в вопросе span был вокруг - такой тег еще раз будет встречаться в строке или нет? Регулярные выражения - это не магия, им тоже нужны четкие условия.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала заменим запятые на точки, если есть, дабы реализовать поддержку дробных чисел, а затем вычистим все, кроме точек и чисел, и преобразуем в float.

```
$ss = str_replace(",",".", "<span>от 5 276 руб.</span>");
echo (float) preg_replace ("#[^.0-9]#", "", $ss);
```

Comment: а что если строка большая? в которой есть этот span? и могут другие цифры попастся?

Comment: Если строка большая или в ней могут попасться другие цифры, то, очевидно, это стоит это указывать в условиях задачи.

Comment: @user236477, пожалуйста, покажите полный пример строки (строк) если на то пошло, из которых нужно изъять числа, а то не понятно, вы сначала говорите одно. потом другое, потом третье... Вы уже определитесь, какая у вас строка (строки) и добавьте в вопрос, а то для решения этой задачи, много вариантов.